# Problem Cannot post in node.js with mongodb (ejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

hello guys i try to make page with form and text input and try to take the value in the other side and get error "Cannot Post". here is my code thanks a lot.
why its not work?
hello guys i try to make page with form and text input and try to take the value in the other side and get error "Cannot Post". here is my code thanks a lot.
why its not work?

this is **app.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var home = require('./home');
var user = require('./user');
var mongodb=require('./mongodb');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
//listen port 3000
app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});


//start ejs package
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
//use the help.js and user.js
app.use('/', home);
app.use('/user', user);
app.use('/mongo',mongodb);
```

this is **mongodb.js:**

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
var app = express();
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');


let obj = null;
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
getDfroMongo();

function getDfroMongo(){
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("mydb");
        //Sort the result by name:
        var sort = { car : 1 };
        dbo.collection("customers").find().sort(sort).toArray(function(err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(result);
          obj = result;
          db.close();
        });
      }); 
}
app.post('/',function(req,res){
  //var myid = {ObjectId:req.body.id};
  var customername = req.body.customername; 
//   var age = req.body.age;
//   var myimg = req.body.img;
//  obj = {CustomerName: customername, Age: age, img: myimg };
  //res.send(htmlData);
 console.log(customername);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render(__dirname + '/views/mongodbview',{result:obj}); //if html file is root directory
});
module.exports = app;
module.exports = router;
```

**mongodbview.ejs:**

```js
<html>

<head>
        <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <%include title%>
</head>

<body>
    <form class="form"  action="/" method="post" name="regForm">   
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="customername" class="form-control" id="customername" placeholder="customername">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="age" class="form-control" id="age" placeholder="age">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="img" class="form-control" id="img" placeholder="img">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>

        <table>
                <tr>
                        <th>Car</th>
                        <th>Model</th>
                        <th>Year</th>
                        <th>image</th>
                </tr><br>
                <% for(let i=0; i < result.length; i++) { %>
                <tr>
                        <td><%= result[i].Car%></td>
                        <td><%= result[i].Model%></td>
                        <td><%= result[i].Year%></td>
                        <td> <img src="\images\<%= result[i].img%> "width="80" height="80"></td><br>
                </tr>
                <% } %>

        </table>
</body>

</html>
```

thanks guys awsome site!!

Comment: Please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Reduce the size of you code blocks to the minimum that is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have res.send commented out in the post handler function. As a result no response is sent to the client.

*Posting this as an answer rather than a comment due to insufficient rep*